# Is it possible to develop Android Studio Plugins in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to figure if it's possible to develop a plugin for Android Studio IN Android Studio?
Everything I was able to find was mixed, some websites/StackOverflow questions claim that Plugins for Android Studio are developed in IntelliJ IDEA or similar IDE because Android Studio doesn't have necessary options, while in the other places I'm able to find some people develop Unity plugins in Android Studio.
Could someone please point me in the right direction? I'm running circles and can't find a definite answer for my Bachelor's Degree Final Project.

The complexity of the plugin can be very simple, it doesn't have to be complicated.
I'm trying to cover the theory behind developing Android Studio plugins (and afterwards will be developing one), but unable to find that answer.

Comment: It seems this is not possible, at least not in a simple way.
You are supposed to develop it in IntelliJ IDEA or a similar IDE that has the necessary tools.

I've managed to make mine in IntelliJ IDEA.